# Excel VBA check multiple values in a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a macro that checks a column for specific values.
I tried my hands on it. It checks for the specific values but the problem is it checks only single value.

For example - Suppose there are three cells.

```
Cell 1 contains Red
Cell 2 contains Black
Cell 3 contains Red;Black
```

After running the macro Cell 3 is highlighted.

Although i have added both the colors in array but it is checking for exact match.

```
    Cells.Find(What:="Color Filter", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

   Dim myarray As Variant

   Dim r As Variant

   myarray = Array("Beige", "Black", "Blue", "Brown", "Cream", "Green", "Grey", "Maroon", "Multi", "Orange", "Pink", "Purple", "Red", "Rust", "Turquoise", "Violet", "White", "Wine", "Yellow", "Transparent")

Dim Rng As Range

Dim Dn As Range

Set Rng = Range(Cells(MyRow, MyCol), Cells(LastRow, MyCol))

    For Each Dn In Rng

    For Each r In myarray

        If Dn = r Then

            Dn.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

        Exit For

   ElseIf Dn = "" Then

   Dn.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

         Else
            Dn.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

    End If

    Next r

Next Dn
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What's not working?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Instr` function to evaluate each member of the array against the Value in the cell. This will look for each color anywhere in the cell value.

I refactored your code slightly so this would work while (I think) keeping your original intent.

```
Dim myarray As Variant, r As Variant

myarray = Array("Beige", "Black", "Blue", "Brown", "Cream", "Green", "Grey", "Maroon", "Multi", "Orange", "Pink", "Purple", "Red", "Rust", "Turquoise", "Violet", "White", "Wine", "Yellow", "Transparent")

Dim Rng As Range, Dn As Range

Set Rng = Range(Cells(MyRow, MyCol), Cells(LastRow, MyCol))

For Each Dn In Rng

    If Dn = "" Then

        Dn.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

    Else

        For Each r In myarray

            If InStr(r, Dn.Value2) Then

                Dn.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
                Exit For

            End If

        Next r

    End If

Next Dn
```

Answer (score 0):

Scott's solution looks right. Another option is to use `split` and then to create a loop... which would somehow allow you to actually *use* the information of each color. So in the case where the cell contains `Red;Black`, it would evaluate once for the first part, and the second time for the second part.

Try like this:

```
Dim myarray As Variant, r,cs,CutString As Variant

myarray = Array("Beige", "Black", "Blue", "Brown", "Cream", "Green", "Grey", "Maroon", "Multi", "Orange", "Pink", "Purple", "Red", "Rust", "Turquoise", "Violet", "White", "Wine", "Yellow", "Transparent")

Dim Rng As Range, Dn As Range

Set Rng = Range(Cells(MyRow, MyCol), Cells(LastRow, MyCol))

For Each Dn In Rng

    If Dn = "" Then

        Dn.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

    Else
        For Each r In myarray
            CutString = Split(Dn.Value2, ";")
            For Each cs In CutString
                If cs = r Then
                    Dn.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next cs
        Next r
    End If    
Next Dn
```